One of two DRV8870 has voltage dip when load is connected
I have this prototype board design with 2 DRV8870DDA chips. One of them is working, the other is not. There are 3 differences,
the not working one has a V+ of 18V, the working one uses +12V. Both are in tollerances. The not working one has V-ref set at 1.5V (which measuered correctly) and the working one has V-ref set at 0.53V which also checks out.
The not working one has it's  Isense pin going to an ADC. There are no internal or external resistors in place.
In KiCad I used the same schematic file for 2 sheets (means that both chips share same schematic)

Content of the sheet:

According to the datasheet's equation, I calculated that Itrip of the not working drv should be: (Risen = 0.05)
1.5 / (10 x 0.05) = 3A
The load draws 23mA. A single LED does work, but as soon as I connect the load I see the voltage drop to roughly 0.05 Volt. If the same load is connected to the working DRV's output, it powers on just fine.

Both schematic and board design passes ERC/DRC. All voltages are what they supposed to be.
The boards are assembled by machine @ JLCPCB. I tried 2 different boards with identical results.
I made one attempt to 'fix' the problem by removing the lower resistor of the V-ref voltage divider. This raised Vref to 5V with no change in outcome.
I don't think the chips are faulty as 2 boads are the same. I suspect it may be board layout thing?
I am trying with toggling the input pins every 1,5s. So there are no high frequencies involved at this point.
So my question therefor is:
Based on the given information, what did I do wrong here?

Hi. In one line you said "The not working one has it's Isense pin going to an ADC. There are no internal or external resistors in place." and in another place, you are using "Risen = 0.05". Which one is it? The impedance of the ADC input is high. If you don't have Risen in place, that makes sense that it doesn't work. All the current for load must pass through the current sense pin.


Which one is it:
Both, the schematics show it. Both chips use 0,05 shunt resistors (2x 0.1R parallel). And the not-working Risen pin also goes to the ADC because I wanted to measure the voltage over the shunt resistors so I can calculate the current in the H-bridge in an MCU.

